# ¿Como pasar un valor de un componente padre y un componente hijo, vuejs?

Tags: vue.js

Tengo el siguiente template de un componente padre:

```
<template>
    <v-card class="pa-3 teal darken-3" flat height="100%">
        <ReportesViales v-bind:visualizar="sheet"></ReportesViales>
        <l-map class="map"  :zoom="zoom" :center="center" :options="{ zoomControl: false }">
            <l-tile-layer :url="url"></l-tile-layer>
            <l-marker :lat-lng="marker">
                <l-popup></l-popup>
            </l-marker>
            <l-control position="bottomleft" >
                <v-btn flat icon color="indigo" @click="ubicacion">
                    <v-icon>my_location</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
                 <v-btn flat icon color="indigo" @click="sheet = true">
                    <v-icon>add_alert</v-icon>
                </v-btn>
            </l-control>
        </l-map>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

y tengo un componente hijo llamado 'ReportesViales'.

Al cual le mando como parametro la variable 'sheet' que basicamente puede ser true o false, tipo boolean.

En el componente hijo lo recibo de la siguiente forma:

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet v-model="visualizar">
        <v-list>
            <v-subheader>Opciones</v-subheader>
            <v-list-tile
            v-for="tile in tiles"
            :key="tile.title"
            @click="visualizar = false"
            >
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                <v-icon :color="tile.color">{{tile.icon}}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-avatar>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ tile.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    props:['visualizar'],
    data(){
        return {
            tiles: [
                { icon: 'notification_important', title: 'Solicitar apoyo', color: '#00695C', tipo: 1 },
                { icon: 'warning', title: 'Reportar alerta', color: '#01579B', tipo: 2 },
                { icon: 'commute', title: 'Transito pesado', color: '#1B5E20', tipo: 3  },
                { icon: 'directions_car', title: 'Transito fluido', color: '#3E2723', tipo: 4 },
                { icon: 'departure_board', title: 'Bloqueado totalmente', color: '#FF3D00', tipo: 5 }
            ]
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

y efectivamente me funciona una vez, pero luego al querer seguir trabajando con este componente aparece el siguiente error, y ya no me funciona el componente hijo:

***Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders***

Answer (score 1):

Lo que esta pasando es que la prop "visualizar" la estas usando como v-model. Y tal cual como dice el error las props no son mutables.

Estas intentando mutarla en el componente v-list title: **@click="visualizar = false"**

**EDITADO**

Puedes resolver tu problema basandote es este ejemplo usando v-model en un componente custom

> Padre.vue

```
<template>
  <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding: 10px;">
    <h3>Componente Padre</h3>
    <button @click="sheet = !sheet">Toggle Sheet</button>
    <p>
      Valor de sheet en padre:
      <strong>{{sheet}}</strong>
    </p>
    <Hijo v-model="sheet"/>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hijo from "./Hijo";

export default {
  name: "Padre",
  components: {
    Hijo
  },
  data() {
    return {
      sheet: true
    };
  }
};
</script>
```

> Hijo.vue

```
<template>
  <div style="border: 1px solid gray; padding: 10px">
    <h4>Componente Hijo</h4>Checkbox componente hijo
    <input v-model="sheetHijo" type="checkbox">
    <p>
      Valor de sheet en hijo:
      <strong>{{sheetHijo}}</strong>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["value"],
  name: "Hijo",
  computed: {
    sheetHijo: {
      get() {
        return this.value;
      },
      set(value) {
        this.$emit("input", value);
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando aquí: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-emit-parent-child-0cqkx

Si revisas el ejemplo puedes ver que al dar click en el boton *Toogle Sheet* cambia el valor de la variable en el componente padre y a su vez cambia el valor del checkbox del componente hijo.

Si cambias el checkbox desde el componente hijo cambia el valor del componente padre.

Otras formas de resolver tu problema si no necesitas cambiar el valor del padre es usando Watch.

```
<script>
import firebase from 'firebase';
export default {
    props:['visualizar'],
    data(){
        return {
            visualizarData: false,
            tiles: [
                { icon: 'notification_important', title: 'Solicitar apoyo', color: '#00695C', tipo: 1 },
                { icon: 'warning', title: 'Reportar alerta', color: '#01579B', tipo: 2 },
                { icon: 'commute', title: 'Transito pesado', color: '#1B5E20', tipo: 3  },
                { icon: 'directions_car', title: 'Transito fluido', color: '#3E2723', tipo: 4 },
                { icon: 'departure_board', title: 'Bloqueado totalmente', color: '#FF3D00', tipo: 5 }
            ]
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.visualizarData = this.visualizar;
    },
    watch: {
        visualizar() {
          this.visualizarData = this.visualizar;
        }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Y luego reemplazas visualizar por visualizarData

```
<template>
    <v-bottom-sheet v-model="visualizar">
        <v-list>
            <v-subheader>Opciones</v-subheader>
            <v-list-tile
            v-for="tile in tiles"
            :key="tile.title"
            @click="visualizar = false"
            >
            <v-list-tile-avatar>
                <v-icon :color="tile.color">{{tile.icon}}</v-icon>
            </v-list-tile-avatar>
            <v-list-tile-title>{{ tile.title }}</v-list-tile-title>
            </v-list-tile>
        </v-list>
    </v-bottom-sheet>
</template>
```

Comment: Gracias, si me funciona una vez, pero creo ha de ser porque el cambio también lo necesito ver reflejado en el componente padre, como se hará ?. Por ejemplo en el componente padre si visualizar paso a false, en el componente padre también tendría que haber cambiado. Muchas gracias de antemano por tu tiempo.

Comment: Entiendo. En ese caso puedes usar un computed property y usar un emit para cambiar el valor del componente padre. Ahora actualizo la respuesta y te dejo un ejemplo

Comment: Ya modifique la respuesta espero que te sirva. Me comentas si tienes mas dudas

Comment: No he podido implementarlo a mi código, debo leer y entender mas sobre ese tema. Te agradezco por el tiempo.